# kyotocabinet java binding installation error

Tags: java, kyotocabinet

I am trying to install kyotocabinet's java binding.
I used mac port to install kyotocabinet (1.2.76). Then I downloaded and unzipped kyoto java binding 1.24.

Next I set the current directory to where kyoto java binding is unzipped.

Now the problem is: When I run ./configure, I get the error "configure: error: kccommon.h is required".
How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the macports installation will not be found by ./configure.

Use the following command to tell configure the location of the original libs:

```
CPPFLAGS="-I/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Headers" ./configure --with-kc=/opt/local/
```

I also added CPPFLAGS as on my Mac (10.8.3) the jni headers were not found, either.

make will also fail, to get this working I appended

```
-I/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Headers
```

to the CPPFLAGS parameter in the Makefile that ./configure created. There might be a less hacky way but this should work.

I wrote a more detailed HowTo some time ago here: http://jhoff.de/kyotocabinet-on-mac/

Answer (score 0):

You need to install c source package first,then install java client see:http://fallabs.com/kyotocabinet/spex.html#installation